# How to extract jvm parameters from binary heap dump

Tags: java, jvm, heap-dump

I am analyzing several heap dumps and am interested in a way that I can get the jvm parameters from the heap dump. Using eclipse memory analyzer I can easy get the System Properties and class path but was wondering if there was a way to get other parameters such as -Xms -Xmx ect.

Comment: It's unlikely they would be there. The heap dump is just Java stuff. The options would mostly be dealt with by the C starter-upper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenJDK / Oracle JDK does not save JVM arguments in a heap dump.